# True or false: Suppose $p$ and $q$ are propositions. Then $\lnot(p\implies q) \equiv p \land q.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I am not very familiar with truth tables but I think that the $\lnot$ should get distributed among both $p$ and $q$ making the problem $\lnot p \implies \lnot q$ which does is not the same as $p\land q$ making the statement false.

I know that $\lnot q \implies \lnot p$ is the contrapositive of $p \implies q$ which is also equivalent to $\lnot p$ or $q$, and if we switch the $p$ and $q$ it will still make it false.

If anyone can confirm my answer or give more of an explanation that would be great as I am very lost!

Thank you to all of the help in advance, it is very appreciated.

Comment: Note that $p \implies q \equiv \neg p \vee q$. So it's negation is $\neg (\neg p \vee q) \equiv p \wedge \neg q$ by De-Morgan's law.

Comment: @AnuragA  Please post your comment as an answer, as it is correct and exactly what I would have answered. (Though I would also have said explicitly that the proposed equivalence by the OP is false.)

Comment: To emphasize a part of @amWhy's comment: $\neg$ does **not** distribute over $\implies$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false.

Consider when both $p$ and $q$ are true. Then the RHS is true, whereas, since $p\implies q$ is true, the LHS is false.